# How to use signalr invoke a function from server side to cancel the upload progress?

Tags: javascript, c#, signalr

Signalr backend controller setup:

```
namespace Antz.App.SignalR.Hubs
{
    public class ProgressHub : Hub
    {
        public static bool IsCancelled = false;

        public void SendProgress(string progressMessage, int progressCount, int totalItems)
        {
            //Thread.Sleep(1);
            var hubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ProgressHub>();
            var percentage = (progressCount * 100) / totalItems;
            hubContext.Clients.All.AddProgress(progressMessage, percentage + "%");
        }

        public void IsCancelledUpload()
        {
            IsCancelled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Javscript:

```
signalrConnection = $.hubConnection("/SignalR", { useDefaultPath: false });
signalrProxy = signalrConnection.createHubProxy('ProgressHub');

signalrProxy.on('AddProgress', function (message, percentage) {

    UpdateProgressBar(percentage);

});

/* signalrConnection.logging = true;*/

signalrConnection.start({ transport: 'longPolling' }).then(function () {

    console.log("Connection Started");

});

signalrConnection.disconnected(function () {
    console.log('Disconnected');

    setTimeout(function () {
        signalrConnection.start({ transport: 'longPolling' }).then(function () {
            console.log("Connection Started");
        });
    }, 3000);
});

signalrConnection.error(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
});

function UpdateProgressBar(percentage) {

    const progressBar = document.querySelector(".progress-bar");
    progressBar.style.opacity = "1";
    progressBar.style.width = percentage;
    progressBar.innerHTML = percentage;

    if (percentage === "100%") {

        progressBar.style.width = "";
        progressBar.innerHTML = "";

    }
}
```

Upload function backend controller:

```
ProgressHub progressHub = new ProgressHub();

var refNoList = new List<string>();
await Task.Run(async () =>
{
    foreach (ArrayList row in data3)
    {
        recordProcessed++;

        rowIndex++;
        // skip row 1 as it's a header
        if (rowIndex == 1)
        {
            continue;
        }

        progressHub.SendProgress("Process in progress...", rowIndex, totalRows);
        //await Task.Delay(5000); // Introduce a small delay

        bool all_pass = true;

        string docType = row[0].ToString().Trim();
        string refNo = row[1].ToString().Trim();
        string vendor = row[2].ToString().Trim();
        string remark = row[3].ToString().Trim();
```

I've tried to put a static field on the class `ProgressHub` and if the user was clicked the cancel button, the button will trigger the signalr to invoke the function `IsCancelledUpload` which is use to update the `IsCancelled` boolean to true. So Excel upload function will check if the boolean is true, the loop will be break. But using static is not a wise choice, so I'm seeking another approach for this.